# Receive IP-address of sender

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, ip

I have a computer connected to two readers through TCP/IP, using UDP protocol.

My code looks like this:

```
IPEndPoint Info = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, MVM.readerProperties.AutoPort);
                    EpcSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    EpcSocket.Bind(Info);
                    IsConnected = true;
                    EpcSocket.BeginReceive(Epcrecebuffer, 0, Epcrecebuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(EpcReceiveCallBack), null);
```

My question is how can I find what IPAdress teh sender has? I need that in my Async function Epcreceivecallback? When using this code the LocalEndpoint is said to be 0.0.0.0

When using one reader I have no issue then I know it's from that one. But when I have two I would like to know from which one the data comes.

Comment: UDP is fundamentally different from TCP, so this might be an UDP/IP package, but not a TCP/IP session.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but question is still Valid, how do I get the sender IP?

Comment: Isn't this the `RemoteEndPoint`? `LocalEndPoint` is *you* endpoint.

Comment: Ok, So then the follow up is :-(..

Comment: Looking at the remote endpoint in my socket it has thrown an exeption!

Comment: Hence value is null :-(

Comment: this is probably because at that moment, you did not yet "listened" to a packet. So at that moment there is no "remote" endpoint.

Comment: I'm doing this in the EpcReceiveCallBAck as below

Comment: private void EpcReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            EndPoint rEP = (EndPoint)remoteEP;

            if (previousReadData == null)
                previousReadData = new ReadData();
            readData = new ReadData();

            if (IsConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    int REnd = EpcSocket.EndReceive(AR);